# Checking Key press whilst tkinter loop is running

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to check if the key "q" is pressed whilst running a tkinter loop. Is there a way to do this?

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard

def DetectKeyPress():
     if keyboard.read_key() == "p":
         print("you pressed p!")

root = Tk()
DetectKeyPress()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Focused tkinter window

To detect if a key is pressed you can use `root.bind('', function)`.
Please be aware that pressing shift and some other keys do count as an independent event.

```
from tkinter import *


def detect_key_press(event):
    if event.char == "p":
         print("you pressed p!")


root = Tk()
root.bind('<Key>', detect_key_press)
root.mainloop()
```

#### Not focused

To detect if a key is pressed while the window is not focused, you have to use keyboard (`pip3 install keyboard`). On Linux, this requires sudo privileges.

```
import keyboard

keyboard.add_hotkey('p', print, args=('you pressed p!',))
keyboard.wait('esc')
```

From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-hotkey-in-python/

Comment: Thanks! is there a way i can detect they key press whilst the window isn't active? Say it was an overlay and i'm playing a game, is there a way to detect that key press whilst i'm playing the game?